# EE 1.6.9 blank page

Tags: blank-screen

I have a very old website made with EE 1.6.9 which was working without problems. I had to move it to another server and while the admin section is working properly, the website it totally blank.

Any idea of the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the new server run a different version of PHP? If possible and you have the option to do so, you could try lowering the version of PHP down to 5.6 or 5.4 and see if that resurrects the site.

Answer (score 0):

Ooof. I hope you have very good luck and this is a simple missing PHP module or something, but EE1.6.9 is going to be very hard to support. I can't find a copy of EE1.X to help much, but a white screen of death (WSOD) is almost always a fatal PHP error occurring before there is any output, resulting in an empty response.

In your `index.php` file, there will be some way to set error reporting all the way on. In EE2+, the way to set debugging on is by setting this variable to a value of 1 in your `index.php`:

```
$debug = 1;
```

I'm not sure if it is the same in EE1.X. If that doesn't work, you can try forcing it using native PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That should get your front end to actually report the error occuring. From there just resolve the error if you can.